# C++ time function returns same value at different calls

Tags: c++, opencv, time

I am trying to get the fps of webcam using the time function in C++. I am using opencv library. For every 100 frames I calculate the fps, so I am sure that at least 1-2 seconds has passed. However, it does not seem to be working, as difftime() returns 0. When I debugged the code I found that both start and end time value is the same. Can someone please help me on this issue? Below is my code:

```
int frameCount = 0;
double seconds;
time_t start,end;
double fps;
for(;;){
    start = time(NULL);
    cap >> src;
    if (!src.empty()) {
        frameCount++;
    }
    if(frameCount == 100){
        end = time(NULL);
        seconds = difftime(end, start); //start and end has same value
        fps = frameCount / seconds;
        frameCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are recording `start` at the beginning of each iteration. It doesn't matter if you record `end` every one hundred iterations, because the `start` value is the one from the current frame.

Move the initialization of `start` to outside your loop, and add it to the end of your every 100 frame check.

```
start = time(NULL);
for(;;){
    cap >> src;
    //...
    if(frameCount == 100){
        end = time(NULL);
        //...
        frameCount = 0;
        start = time(NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why comparing frameCount with 100? I see no good reason for it if you just need the fps.

```
    start = time(NULL); // -> it needs to be initialized outside the loop, otherwise, it will always be equal to end
    for (;;){

        cap >> src;
        if (!src.empty()) {
            frameCount++;
        }

        end = time(NULL);
        seconds = difftime(end, start); 

        if (seconds != 0)
        { 
            fps = frameCount / seconds;
            frameCount = 0;
            start = time(NULL); // -> reset here the start time
        }
    }
```